# Command line filtering of words in a line of text

Tags: python, command-line, grep, filtering

How can I filter out some words from a line of text using command line tools?

Example:

```
line 1: All's Well That Ends Well
filter: That Well
output: Well That Well
```

Notice: a double occurrence still appears twice after the filtering.

Apart from a line of GNU utilities, I could also employ a Python script.

Comment: One idea would be to play around with Python regular expressions and parse that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `\b` to match word boundaries too. Longer words (such as `Wellness`) will be rejected.

```
echo "All's Well That Ends Well" | grep -o '\(\bThat\b\|\bWell\b\)'
```

Comment: As I commented above. Your modified solution satisfies the requirement. I'll wait to accept to see if there's a more efficient way to do this... but this looks correct to me! I learned about (-o) !

Answer (score 2):

You can send (pipe) the text into `grep` like this:

```
echo "All's Well That Ends Well" | grep -o '\(That\|Well\)'
```

Comment: Accepts longer words, such as `Wellness` too.

Comment: I did not know about -o! So, this should work to match whole words? echo "All's Well That Ends Well" | grep -o '\(\bThat\b\|\bWell\b\)' | tr '\n' ' '; printf "\n" -- The tr + printf looks clunky though. How to improve?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l="All's Well That Ends Well"
>>> k=['Well','That']
>>> [w for w in l.split() if w in k]
```

How do I do this using shell scripting?

Comment: **Well,** this sentence wouldn't be accepted because of the comma.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

```
line = "All's Well That Ends Well"
filter = "That Well"

print [word.lower() for word in line.split() if word.lower() in filter.split()]
```

That last line is called a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), and is very "pythonic." split() makes any string into a list of words where each item in the list is determined by whitespace between words.  I added lower() so that it would return words in lowercase, ignoring the original case.

Comment: `.split()` is bad at treating commas within sentences.

Comment: True, there are a lot things to consider if this problem is to cover a lot of cases.

Comment: So, how do I do it better then?

Comment: Here's a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python) about removing punctuation from a string.  You should do that before the list comprehension line.